# Simanim on Rosh Hashanah

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year

Halacha (Kitzur) brings that besides for the Simanim (symbolic foods) mentioned in the Gemara Horiyas and Shulchan Aruch you can Make your own according to the Language of the Country you live in, this had lead to some creative stuff lets see some original Ideas for the Yehi Ratzons and symbolic foods (the  example in the Kitzur brings carrots(Meren) which in Yiddish the language of his country also means to inrease)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget Dates for dates...

Comment: Assuming you're single!  (Or "date night" with your spouse?)

Answer (score 5):

In the spirit of "Kawl HaOmer Davar Bishem Amro", Rav Moshe Heineman came up with the siman "Lettuce, half a raisin, celery"="Let us have a raise in salary."

Comment: I knew that went around, but never heard it in R' Heinemann's name ...

Comment: I grew up in Baltimore and it was common knowledge (through his children) that he did this siman at his table on Rosh HaShanah.

Comment: @yahu It's confirmed by the STAR-K: "Rav Heinemann shlita introduced a now famous Baltimore siman to take lettuce, half a raisin and celery as an indication to ‘let-us-have-a-raise-in-salary’." https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/628/starting-the-new-year-right-a-guide-to-the-simanim-on-rosh-hashana/

Answer (score 3):

I have heard Raisin and celery for a raise in salary and Sardines To be saar (remove) the din
Ice Scream for a good new year

Answer (score 3):

Lishana haba'a byrushalayim hab[Beera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer)!

לשנה הבאה בירושלים ה[בירה](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94)

Answer (score 3):

I came up with Schnitzel a few years ago, as in שניצל מכל אויבנו. 
I just heard this week that Belzer Hassidim eat Sardines on Rosh HaShanah night as a siman for סר דין which means "removal of din".

Answer (score 2):

Two I used for the first time this year:

- Over apple cider: "Yehi ratzon ... sheta'azreinu leSADER et chayyeinu." - "May it be the Will of God ... that You help us order our lives."
- Over papaya: "Yehi ratzo ... sheteracheim 'aleinu keracheim AV 'al banim." - "May it be the Will of God ... that You have mercy on us as a FATHER has mercy on his children."

Answer (score 2):

Pomegranate - Sh'itpotzetzu soneinu kerimon.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on one for apples that would be in the pun (rather than sensory) category. Perhaps י

> יהי רצון שלא **יפיחו** חמס נגדינו

?

Comment: May it be Your will that You *apply* mercy to us in judgement.

Comment: "Yehi ratzon shetasim aleinu rachamim badin." No less intelligible than "sheyirbu zechuyoteinu" with a carrot is for Yiddish speakers.

Comment: Or, how about: יהי רצון שתיפח עצמן של שונאינו?